# Is this kind of question "unclear what you're asking" or "too broad?

Tags: discussion, flags, specific-question, close-reasons

What should a question like [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/110729/im-following-the-blender-beginner-tutorial-part-5-im-trying-to-extrude-and-it) be flagged for? I'm torn between "unclear what you're asking" and "too broad".
My problem here is indeed applicable to other sites, too. This question on the blender site can be just seen as an example, used for the purposes of my question. I want to know what to do if a question does not provide enough detailed information ("too broad"), which makes the question unclear ("unclear what your asking"). I think this kind of question isn't that rare which makes answers applicable to other sites/topics, too.

Comment: This is certainly a problem that occurs across the network; I know at Arqade we encounter it regularly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ultimately, it doesn't matter. We <s>close questions</s> put questions on hold because we want the author to **edit** them into a form where it's acceptable for the site. Both close reasons (visible to the author after the post is put on hold) mention this:

> **unclear what you're asking**
>
> Please *clarify* your specific problem or *add* additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. *See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.*

> **too broad**
>
> Please *edit* the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. *See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.*

Answer (score 3):

Whichever you feel matches closest to how you think. It doesn't ultimately matter which you pick, and it's okay for close voters to use both reasons between them. If you think the question is problematic for both reasons, if you wish you can write a comment explaining so and asking for both clarity and specificity.